# Cannot Attach ajax:error handler to Form ID

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I am having trouble binding an ajax:error response to a form ID.  Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Here is the code.

```
<%= form_for @person,
              html: {
                id: '#person_form',
                class: 'js_inline_validate'
              },
              data: { validate_url: validate_field_people_path },
              remote: true,
              url: people_path do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='form-group-label'>
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
    </div>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name,
                      :id => 'first_name',
                      class: 'js_new_person_frm_validate js_new_person_first_name' %>
    <div class="text-error small">
      <span>
        <%= @person.errors.full_messages_for(:first_name).first if @person.errors[:first_name].any? %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='form-group-label'>
      <%= f.label :last_name %>
    </div>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name,
                      :id => 'last_name',
                      class: 'js_new_person_frm_validate js_new_person_last_name' %>
    <div class="text-error small">
      <span>
                <%= @person.errors.full_messages_for(:last_name).first if @person.errors[:last_name].any? %>
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Create", data: { disable_with: false } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  ......

  def create
    @person = Person.new(create_params)

    if(@person.save)
      flash[:success] = "person created successfully"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :action => 'new' }
        format.any(:js, :json) {
          render :json => { :error => @person.errors }, :status => 422
        }
      end
    end
  end

  .....

end
```

CoffeeScript

```
$ ->

  $("#person_form").on "ajax:error", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert "ajax:error!"
    #do more stuff
```

The issue I cannot solve is this works as below when I use 'document', but I need this to be specific to my #person_form.  And I get no response when I replace document with my form_id.  Am I missing something simple here?

```
$ ->

      $(document).on "ajax:error", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
        alert "ajax:error!"
        #do more stuff
```

Thank You!

Comment: I'm returning the model errors in json.  So on success I redirect but I want the json errors on failure.  It works fine as long as the Ajax event is handled globally (i.e. With document) but I get no response when I try to attach the handler to the specific form ID.  I'm assuming I'm missing something very simple in the script?  But I'm stumped!

Comment: Sorry, there was a misspelling. Do you render your form via Ajax?

Comment: Nope, I am not re-rendering the form.  I'm only returning the model.errors object back to the client via json:  render :json => { :error => @person.errors }, :status => 422

Comment: Try `$('#person_form input[type=submit]').on "ajaxError", -> alert('work')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this simple answer out here for anyone else who may run across this issue.  Hopefully, it's this simple for the next person.  It took me HOURS to track down the problem.

It turns out the error was happening because of a very simple mistake:

```
<%= form_for @person,
      html: {
        id: '#person_form',  <= ERROR IS HERE!!
        class: 'js_inline_validate'
      },
      data: { validate_url: validate_field_people_path },
      remote: true,
      url: people_path do |f| %>
```

The #person_form should have been person_form (excluding the pound sign).  Just a very simple error in code I didn't catch when switching from script to ruby.

The global event handler would catch the ajax:error and execute the code properly.  The pound sign in the identifier was preventing the proper registration of the local ajax event.